# Setting kendo grid height scrollable auto min-height max-height

Tags: kendo-ui, grid

I am aware of this beeing a frequently discussed issue.
Anyway I want to give it a shot:
I am using multiple kendo grids - so I am looking for a reusable and clean way how to set the grids styles without having side effects on each other.
So here's what I want to achieve:
Grid style 1:
 - min-height: 150px max-heigt: 600px scrollable
Grid style 2:
 - min-height: 150px max-heigt: 300px scrollable

Doesn't seem very extraordinary, does it?
I tryed setting html.attributes, setting scrollable() height and overwriting css.
But in the end I'll always find myself in having following problems, though:

1. Grid content div overflows the parent div
2. no scrollbars anymore
3. "fixing" by overwriting css classes what has undesired side effects
   of course

Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: A [scoped style sheet](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style_scoped.asp) would be great for this kind of problem but unfortunately it is still an experimental feature only supported fully by FireFox.

Answer (score 1):

I have a possible solution which I have modified from a bit of code I use.

[independent grid height resizing](http://dojo.telerik.com/EWicE/3)

So lets examine the magic bit for you:

```
     function resizeGrid(grid, size, fixed, minHeight, minSizeHeight, maxHeight, maxSizHeight) {

   if (size === null || size === undefined) {
     size = 0.6;
   }

   if (minHeight === null || minHeight === undefined) {
     minHeight = 600;
     minSizeHeight = 150;
   }

   if (maxHeight === null || maxHeight === undefined) {
     maxHeight = 800;
     maxSizHeight = 600;
   }

   var windowHeight = $(window).height();
   if (!fixed) {
     windowHeight = windowHeight * size;
   } else {
     windowHeight = size;
   }

   if ($(window).height() < minHeight) {
     windowHeight = minSizeHeight;
   }

   if ($(window).height() > maxHeight) {
     windowHeight = maxSizHeight;
   }


   var gridContent = $("#" + grid + " div.k-grid-content");
   var lockedContent = $("#" + grid + " div.k-grid-content-locked");

   gridContent.height(windowHeight);

   if (lockedContent !== null && lockedContent !== undefined) {
     lockedContent.height(windowHeight);

   }


 }
```

So based on your requirements and my understanding you want to be able to change the `scrollable` area dynamically and independently of one another.

in this example we provide the following signature:

resizeGrid(grid, size, fixed, minHeight, minSizeHeight, maxHeight, maxSizeHeight)

Grid ==> the id of the grid we are working with
Size ==> this is the size either expressed as a pixel value or percentage (eg. 150 or 0.4 (40%)) 
fixed ==> this tells the function if the value passed is a fixed height or a percentage height for the initial height requirements
minHeight==> this should be the minimum screen size that the grid should resize itself
minSizeHeight ==> this is the size the grid should resize to if the minHeight condition is met. 
maxHeight ==> this should be the maximum screen size that the grid should resize itself. 
maxSizeHeight ==> this should be the maximum size of the grid should be be above the maxHeight of the window.

**Note: the final 4 settings will use pixel defined values but the code could be adapted to work with percentages as well**

so in the example I have provided I have declared:

```
 resizeGrid("grid",600,true, 400,150, 800,600 );
 resizeGrid("grid2",150,true, 300,300, 600,400 );
```

So the first grid `#grid` will set itself to a size of 600px initially and then resize itself if the window goes below 400px and over 800px. In both scenarios it will resize to 150px, 600px respectively.

then when we start resizing the window I have added this:

```
  $(window).resize(function () {
          console.log("resizing::" ,$(window).height() );
         resizeGrid("grid",600,true, 400,150, 800,600 );
          resizeGrid("grid2",150,true, 300,300, 600,400 ); 
        });
```

This will then look for the window resize event to be fired off and then resize the grids accordingly.

I have added the console statement purely so you can see this event being fired off and what the `window` height is to check the code is being `activated` at the right point.

One thing you may notice are these lines here:

```
   var gridContent = $("#" + grid + " div.k-grid-content");
   var lockedContent = $("#" + grid + " div.k-grid-content-locked");
```

Due to the grid "wrapping" the locked and non-locked portions into different tags I am checking to see if there are any locked columns as otherwise you will have different scrolling/unexpected style on the various parts of the grid.

If you need anything more explaining/changing let me know and I will update my answer accordingly. Hopefully this is what you are after.

**Edit: I have updated the example so you can see the grids side by side**